# Where to look for the source code of `Findcontour`

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am looking for the source code of the `findcontour` function in CV2. I wanted to implement this function from scratch. I have gone through the theory in the paper `Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following`. I wanted to see do the implementation is done in python.

Answer (score 2):

The rabbit hole begins at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp#L1793

Good luck ;)

The library is written in C++. There is no Python code. When you use it in Python, Python calls compiled functions.

Comment: But the code is in CPP. I am looking for the python implementation.

Comment: there isn't any. this is the code. when you use it from python, this code is doing the work.

Comment: No body implemented find contour function in python from scratch ?  Actually I  am trying to creating function of my own and compare  the result with opencv result. Towards this end  is there any materials or resource which help to achieve this goal.